# $\left(\frac1\alpha-\frac1\beta\right)^2$ for $p(x)=x^2+x-2$

Tags: polynomials, roots

If $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the zeroes of the quadratic polynomial $p(x)=x^2+x-2$,
then $\left(\frac1\alpha-\frac1\beta\right)^2 is:$

A) $\frac94$
B) $\frac{-9}4$
C) $\frac25$
D) $\frac{-2}5$

This is a homework question from our school's home assignment for class 10. I tried this:

We can write $p(x)=x^2+x-2$ as $$p(x)=\underbrace{(1)x^2}_{ax^2}
+\underbrace{(1)x}_{bx}+\underbrace{(2)}_c$$ Therefore, $$a=1\quad
b=1\quad c=2$$ We know that $$\alpha\beta=\frac ca=2$$ and
$$\alpha+\beta=\frac{-b}{a}=-1$$ Now $$\left(\frac1\alpha-\frac1
\beta\right)^2=\left(\frac{\alpha-\beta}{\alpha\beta}\right)^2=
\frac{(\alpha-\beta)^2}{(\alpha\beta)^2}=\frac{\alpha^2+\beta^2-2
\alpha\beta}4=\frac{\alpha^2+\beta^2-4}4$$

I got stuck here. What to do now?

Comment: Use $$(\alpha-\beta)^2=(\alpha+\beta)^2-4\alpha\beta$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee Thanks. I got it.

Comment: c = - 2, I suppose

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes it is -2. thanks

Comment: @Kartik. You welcome !

Comment: An additional remark: notice that answers b and d could already never be true in any case because of the square $\left((\frac{1}{\alpha}-\frac{1}{\beta})^2>0\right)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\alpha^2 + \beta^2 = (\alpha+\beta)^2 - 2\alpha\beta$

Comment: @hardik Thanks. I got it.

Comment: Should it not be $-4\alpha\beta$ ?

Comment: It's $2$. Expanding $(\alpha + \beta)^2$ gives you $\alpha^2 + 2 \alpha \beta + \beta^2$. lab bhattacharjee uses $4$ because he's equating it to $(\alpha - \beta)^2$, not $\alpha^2 + \beta^2$.

Comment: @HenrySwanson Yes, I did not read it properly.

Comment: @Kartik no problem :)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem in a single swoop. Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the polynomial $x^2+x-2$ therefore we must have $\alpha$=-2 and $\beta$=1(or vice versa). Hence
$$\left(\frac1\alpha-\frac1\beta\right)^2=(-\frac12-1)^2$$

Comment: Since this was a homework question, I would bet that Kartik is "supposed" to do it the way s/he detailed in the post.

Comment: @HenrySwanson Yes, I am 'supposed' to do it that way but it is not *written* in the question to do it that way.

Comment: True, in this case it's not hard to find the roots. But it's significantly less enjoyable when you have cubics or quartics, so the method you use is more generalizable. (as long as the expression you're computing is symmetric in all variables)

Comment: Another possible way would be to write the quadratic whose roots are $\frac1\alpha$ and $-\frac1\beta$

Answer (score 1):

$(x+\frac{1}{2})^2-\frac{1}{4} -2 =0 \iff (x+\frac{1}{2})^2=\frac{9}{4} \iff x=1$ or $x=-2$

Since we know that $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the roots of the polynomial, it must hold that $\alpha =1$ and $\beta=-2$ *or* $\alpha=-2$ and $\beta=1$

Lets first consider the case in which $\alpha =1$ and $\beta=-2.  \Rightarrow (\frac{1}{\alpha}-\frac{1}{\beta})^2=(1+\frac{1}{2})^2=\frac{9}{4}$

In the case in which $\alpha=-2$ and $\beta=1 \Rightarrow (\frac{1}{\alpha}-\frac{1}{\beta})^2=(-\frac{1}{2}-1)^2=\frac{9}{4}$, so we arrive at the same result.